# Showing instablity of differential equation.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, fluid-dynamics, stability-in-odes

Assume differential equation

> $$ x'=2x+y+x \cos t-y \sin t $$
>   $$ y'=-x+2y-x\cos t+y \sin t $$

1. Show that solution $(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$ is unstable.
2. Is there a non-trival solution such that $\lim_{t\to \infty}(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$.

for question 2 , I think there exist a non-trival solution such that $\lim_{t\to \infty}(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$ and it shows that having zero limit at infinity doesn't show stablity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question**

Multiply the first equation by $x'$, the second by $y'$ and add:
$$
x\,x'+y\,y'=2(x^2+y^2)+x^2\cos t+y^2\,\sin t-2\,x\,y\cos t\sin t.
$$
If $0\le t\le\pi/2$ then $0\le\cos t\le1$, $0\le\sin t\le1$ and
$$\begin{align}
x^2\cos t+y^2\,\sin t-2\,x\,y\cos t\sin t&\ge x^2\cos^2 t+y^2\,\sin^2 t-2\,x\,y\cos t\sin t\\
&=(x\cos t-y\sin t)^2\\
&\ge0.
\end{align}$$
Thus, if $0\le t\le\pi/2$ then
$$
(x^2+y^2)'\ge4(x^2+y^2).
$$
Integrating
$$
x^2+y^2\ge(x(0)^2+y(0)^2)e^{4t},\quad 0\le t\le\frac\pi2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The equation is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2+\cos(t)&1-\sin(t)\\
-1-\cos(t)&2+\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
Although the trace of the square matrix above is $4+\sqrt2\sin(t+\pi/4)$ which is positive for all $t$, Artem has pointed out [an article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1100529) in which an example is given where *some* of the eigenvalues have positive real part yet the system is stable.

---

**Another approach**

In an approach similar to Julián Aguirre's answer, we can write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2+\cos(t)&1-\sin(t)\\
-1-\cos(t)&2+\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
Noting that the eigenvalues of the symmetric part of the matrix in $(2)$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2+\cos(t)&-\tfrac12(\sin(t)+\cos(t))\\
-\tfrac12(\sin(t)+\cos(t))&2+\sin(t)
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
$$
are
$$
\frac{4\pm\sqrt2+\sin(t)+\cos(t)}2\tag{4}
$$
we get that for all $t$,
$$
(2-\sqrt2)
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
\le\begin{bmatrix}
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\y'
\end{bmatrix}
\le(2+\sqrt2)
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
$$
That is,
$$
(4-2\sqrt2)(x^2+y^2)\le(x^2+y^2)'\le(4+2\sqrt2)(x^2+y^2)\tag{6}
$$
which implies that
$$
e^{(4-2\sqrt2)t}(x_0^2+y_0^2)\le x^2+y^2\le e^{(4+2\sqrt2)t}(x_0^2+y_0^2)\tag{7}
$$
Inequality $(7)$ shows that $(0,0)$ is not stable and is the only solution for which $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}(x,y)=(0,0)$ (in fact, the only solution for which $(x,y)$ remains bounded).

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot invoke the eigenvalues while studying problems with non-constant matrices.

Comment: @Artem: locally (that is, for $t$ close to some $t_0$), the propagation of $(x,y)$ will be very close to that given by the matrix given above evaluated at $t_0$. Since the action of that constant matrix is unstable at every point, we get the same instability.

Comment: No, this is just handwaving. There are examples of time dependent matrices that have constant negative eigenvalues. And the oring is unstable.

Comment: @Artem: is there an example of a time dependent matrix with constant *positive* eigenvalues that are *stable*?

Comment: I am not aware of any. However, it does not prove anything, since, as I mentioned, you cannot invoke these kind of arguments dealing with time-dependent matrices.

Comment: You can find an example in Wu, 1974, A Note on Stability of Linear Time-Varying System.

Comment: @Artem: In that paper, only some of the eigenvalues have positive real part. In the answer above, I only show that the sum of the eigenvalues have positive real part, although it is the case that *both* of the eigenvalues have positive real part.  I am working on a reply to the second part of the question in which I show that both eigenvalues have positive real part, but I may change that part as well. I will edit soon.

Comment: I am really surprised that you continue to give me this kind of arguments. Your answer can be fixed, if you forget about the eigenvalues and work directly with the trace. However, as I already mentioned several times, no conclusion can be made based on the eigenvalues of time dependent matrix. Moreover, as the answer stands right now, it is simply wrong. -1.

Comment: @Artem: I was agreeing with you ("but I may change that part as well") and changing my answer ("I will edit soon"). Please read my edited answer.

Comment: +1 The eigenvalues of $(A(t)+A(t)^\top)$ work. Unfortunately, this is a very conservative test and does not work always.

Comment: @Artem: If you are so inclined, would you post an answer and show how I could have fixed my answer using the trace directly? Thanks.

Comment: Since the matrix is $T$-periodic, by Floque theory the fundamental matrix solution is $X(t)=P(t)e^{tB}$, where $P(t)$ is $T$-periodic and $B$ is constant. For eigenvalues of $B$ one has $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \rm{tr}\, A(t)dt$, from which it follows that the origin is unstable. I am not sure that I can right now answer the second question (shorter than you).

Comment: @Artem: Thanks for your comments. I will look into Floque theory. I had been considering trying to adapt the method of integrating factors to this problem. The form of the answer you give looks reminiscent.

Comment: @Artem: nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which stability criterion should be applied, so I try a simple argument:

An object at the origin $(0,0)$ which is disturbed by a small positive displacement $\epsilon$ in $x$-direction will experience a velocity $x' = (2 + \cos t) \epsilon > 0$, it will move away from the origin.

For a small disturbance $\epsilon$ in $y$-direction it will experience a velocity $y' = (2 + \sin t) \epsilon > 0$, which will move the object away as well.

About the second part I am not sure, because of the instability at $(0,0)$, something there could only stay, if undisturbed.

Here is a plot of the velocity field for $t=0$:

[image: t = 0]

Comment: @mvm :thanks alot